# How do I use z-index (or should I) when arranging these images?

Tags: javascript, css, z-index

I am currently using an `.onload` to randomly arrange images upon opening of the browser. When the page is loaded, the images randomly "spread" onto the page. When they are clicked, they are brought to a specific coordinate on the screen. The first image is a recycling bin. I would like for this image to be the center image and for all other images to go inside it (or in this case "behind" it). Should I set up a z-index for every individual image? Here is what I have:

Any suggestions are helpful!

```
<html>

<head>
<style>
    body{
        padding: 0;
        margin: 0;   
    }

    div{
        position: fixed;
        top: 0;
        left: 300;
        width: 35%;
        height: 35%;
        float: left;
        transition: width 5s, top 5s, left 5s;
    }

    div:hover{
        width: 100%;
    }


</style>
</head>


<body>
   <div class="div">
    <a target="_blank">
     <img src="curbside%20collection%20empty%20yellow%20bin.png" alt= width=100% height=100%>
    </a>
   </div>


   <div class="div">
    <a target="_blank">
     <img src="Bomb.png" alt= width=50% height=50%>
    </a>
   </div>

   <script>
    document.body.onload = function() {
        var mycolours = [];
        var elements = 
        document.getElementsByTagName("div");
        for(var i = 0; i < elements.length; i++){
            elements[i].style.backgroundColor =
                mycolours[i%mycolours.length]; // remainder operator magic
                    elements[i].style.top = Math.random() * innerHeight;
                    elements[i].style.left = Math.random() * innerWidth;

            elements[i].onclick = function(){
                console.log(this.style.top);

                if(this.style.top === "300px"){
                    this.style.top = Math.random() * window.innerHeight;
                    this.style.left = Math.random() * window.innerWidth;
                }

                else{
                    this.style.top = 300;
                    this.style.left = 500;
                }       
              }
         }
    }
</script>

</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest using `class`'s instead of having to set each image's `z-index` This way you can set the properties of, lets say, your image class to all have a certain `z-index` and then you can also have another class for recycle bins

I also believe your current use of `class` is wrong.

In order to select a DOM element with a class in CSS you are supposed to use a `.` (period) as the prefix. The way you are using it your CSS is selecting the `div` DOM element

ie.

```
#div { //properties of the element with "div" as the ID }
.div { //properties of all elements with the "div" class }
div  { //properties of <div> elements }
```

Keep in mind - a Class can be applied to multiple Elements inside of a DOM, but an ID can only be applied to one element inside of a DOM.